# Changed GRUB settings now can't load Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 13.04, grub2, dual-boot, windows

I changed the timer setting on GRUB to 0 seconds, this was accidental.

Now my computer boots straight into Windows 8 as this was my default GRUB option.

Since the GRUB menu no longer appears (as the delay is 0 seconds) I can't boot into Ubuntu.

Is there any way to change the GRUB settings from Windows OR boot into Ubuntu in another way?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I know this sounds simple, but have to held the down arrow before it is due to come on the screen? Otherwise you will need an application to view ext2/4 partitions in windows and edit the `/etc/default/grub` file from there. [How to read Ext3/Ext4 linux partition from windows 7](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-read-ext3ext4-linux-partition-from-windows-7.html)

Comment: I did try holding the arrow key but unfortunately it didn't work. I'll have a go at viewing the partitions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just load up your Ubuntu CD/DVD and instead of installing, just choose the 'Try it out' option. You'll be able to edit the `grub.cfg` file on the partition you installed Ubuntu on and change the timeout.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi there! I did what you said and used the Try it now, and eventually managed to change the timeout by editing the grub.cfg by accessing it through terminal. It worked. So thanks for your help (telling me to log in via Trial version)! :)

Comment: @user68186 No, the answer is not wrong. The file name I listed was wrong. I told the OP to boot into a live environment and fix it that way. Downvoting was not necessary. A simple edit would've sufficed.

Comment: @user170732 You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Boot repair tool from the following link:http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/
2. Then burn it on CD or put it on USB key via Unetbootin.
3. Insert the Boot-Repair-Disk and reboot the PC.
4. Select Advanced option. There you can find boot menu timer option. Change as you like and apply.
5. Shut down your computer and remove boot cd and start again.

Comment: Thanks for this, already managed to fix it though. This seems much simpler than what I did so I'll remember it incase I do it again, hopefully I don't though, hehe.